# Entity Framework and duplicates

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I use Entity Framework as ORM in my project. Let's suppose I use Code-First pattern and I have two models. Such as

```
internal class First
{        
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int  Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

internal class Second
{        
    public int  Id { get; set; }

    public First ForeignKeyEntity { get; set; }

    // other members
}
```

And here is code populating database:

```
List<Second> res = GetData();
using (var ctx = new StatisticContext())
{
    foreach (var item in res)
    {
        ctx.Seconds.Add(item);
    }
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

As you can see each instance of class `Second` has instance of class `First` in its member `ForeignKeyEntity`. Obviously some instances of `First` can be duplicated in res. And when I run this code I get DbUpdateException in `ctx.SaveChanges()` with inner exception that has the following message:

```
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.First'. 
Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.First'. 
The duplicate key value is (29459). The statement has been terminated.
```

I can not to insert duplicated rows but I don't want to insert duplicates, I would like to insert row only if it doesn't exist. How to solve this problem? How to insert foreign key object only if doesn'tt exist?

Comment: what is the relationship `First : Second` ?

Comment: @Sampath Every instance of Second has an instance of First. As for database I have two tables: First and Second. And Second has a foreign key to Id in table First

Comment: is that mean `1:1` ?

Comment: what is this `GetData()` ?

Comment: @Sampath no 1 : many. GetData is some abstract method that returns List<Second>

Comment: you have to show that method.problem is on that method.`GetData()` ?

Comment: @Sampath method GetData is fictional. The problem is hiding not in this method

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 1):

The normal way of doing things would be to do a read first with item to see if it exists. If it does then you need to use `ctx.Seconds.Update(item);`

If your items are already on the context, then you can check the state. it will be either `State.Modified` or `State.Added`.

Whats in GetData()